# Xamarin.Forms could not be updated

Tags: android, macos, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am using `Xamarin.Forms` for Mac. I want to update `Xamarin.Form` package under `.Droid` project but I get the following error:

```
Updating Xamarin.Forms...
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.0.1.3)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (= 23.0.1.3)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (≥ 23.0.1.3)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView (= 23.0.1.3)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter (= 23.0.1.3)'.
Looking for updates for 'Xamarin.Forms'...
Updating 'Xamarin.Forms' from version '1.3.5.6335' to '2.0.0.6490' in project 'testienjte.Droid'.
Already referencing a newer version of 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4'.
```

Any idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: Whats the actual error, I don't see one there?

Comment: Well, since I cannot update Xamarin.Forms ( new in Xamarin.Studio) I cannot build  the project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms 2.0.0.6490 is tied to a single version 23.0.1.3 of the Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.

The error message suggests that you have a newer version of Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 than Xamarin.Forms supports so you will need to uninstall Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 and then install the same version or just install the latest Xamarin.Forms NuGet package.

Comment: You just need to remove all Xamarin references and add `Xamarin.Forms`, it would automatically add all other xamarin.adnroid references

Answer (score -1):

Please follow this steps:

1. Download the next extension for Xamarin 5.0

   https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-extensions
2. Follow the instructions to install the nuget extension. This is required for download a specific version of the packages used by xamarin forms.
3. After the nuget extesion is installed please remove from the android project the next packages in the next order

   Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView
   Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter
   Xamarin.Android.Support.Design
   Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat
   Xamarin.Android.Support.v4
   Xamarin.Forms
4. Now install the next packages in the follow order

   Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 -version 23.0.1.3
   Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat  -version 23.0.1.3
   Xamarin.Android.Support.Design -version 23.0.1.3
   Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView  -version 23.0.1.3
   Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter  -version 23.0.1.3
5. Install the most recent Xamarin.Forms package (2.1.0.6529)